# wro4j and bootstrap glylphicons

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, jakarta-ee, spring-boot

I'm kind of new on the wro4j thing so I will try to explain at best, do not hesitate to ask more informations, I ll update the post as necessary.

I'm trying to use boostrap and angular within a single dependency generate by wro4j (version 1.8.0).

here is my wro.xml :

```
<groups xmlns="http://www.isdc.ro/wro">
  <group name="angular-bootstrap">
    <css>webjar:bootstrap/3.3.7-1/css/bootstrap.css</css>
    <css>file:${project.basedir}/src/main/wro/main.less</css>
    <js>webjar:jquery/3.1.0/jquery.js</js>
    <js>webjar:angularjs/1.5.8/angular.js</js>
    <js>webjar:angularjs/1.5.8/angular-route.js</js>
    <js>webjar:angularjs/1.5.8/angular-resource.js</js>
    <js>webjar:angular-ui-router/0.2.18/angular-ui-router.js</js>
    <js>webjar:bootstrap/3.3.7-1/js/bootstrap.js</js>
  </group>
</groups>
```

my main.less :

```
@brand-primary: #de8579;
```

my wro.properties :

```
preProcessors=lessCssImport
postProcessors=less4j,jsMin
```

My problem is when I am trying to use the glyphicons of bootstrap : I keep getting have the 404 error on these resources :

```
GET http://localhost:8080/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2     
GET http://localhost:8080/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff 
GET http://localhost:8080/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf
```

My static resources folder contains the following folder

```
resources
 /-static
   /-css
      /- custom.css
   /-fonts (empty)
   /-img
      /- brandimage.png
   /-js
      /- custom.js
   /-views
      /- views of application (non relevant)
```

On the target folder I'm having the following arborescence :

```
classes
 /-static
   /-css
      /- custom.css
      /- angular-boostrap.css
   /-img
      /- brandimage.png
   /-js
      /- custom.js
      /- angular-boostrap.js
   /-views
      /- views of application (non relevant)
```

but none of the fonts/glyphicons of bootstrap is generated... 
What I am missing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've manager to workaround this issue by importing myself the missing resources from bootstrap 3.3.7 and adding them to my resources/static/fonts folders